# NServiceBus 4.0.3 Message has failed FLR and will be handed over to SLR, doesnt gets into SLR

Tags: .net, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I see this message and I cant see second level retries happening.
I can see the message ending up in .timeouts queue.

I have seen the sample app from nservice bus which works all ok any idea what i would be missing. I have enable SLR in code and added the config value too.

Comment: Messages getting stuck in the Timeouts queue is a sign that the TimeoutManager isn't running. You haven't by any chance disabled it?

Comment: I have got timeout manager disabled. why do I need to  need enable it? And where does Slr store the message?  Does timeout which we use in saga and SLR are both one and the same under the hood? We are using timeout manager in saga with nhibernate persistence. Ideally if nservicebus would have thrown an error it would have been much easier to figure it out that I need to enable timeout manager.

Comment: In-order to use SLRs you need to enable Timeouts. The timeouts are all the same under the hood. Agree on throwing an error, please log an issue in github